# How to dynamically zoom a HTML element without affecting its parents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page where a draggable and zommable grid is rendered.

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">   

    <div id="top_div">          
    <!-- some GUI -->
    </div>
    <div id="central_container">
        <div id="grid_container_static">
            <div id="grid_container_movable">
                <table id="grid">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom_div">
    <!-- some GUI -->
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$( function() {
        $("#grid_container_movable").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
<style>
body, html{
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    background-color: green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#central_container{
    background-color: red;

    min-height: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
}
#grid_container_static{
    overflow: hidden;      
}
</style>
```

Table's cells are dynamically rendered as square tiles with css class `.tile`. If the grid total size exceeds the grid_container_static space, the exceeding portion is hidden behind the parents without affecting them. The user can drag the grid to see the hidden portions. So far, everything works.

I wrote a javascript zoom function that dynamically changes the grid tiles size when the mouse scroll is detected:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
        const delta = Math.sign(event.deltaY);     
        
        if(delta < 0){
            current_tile_size ++;
        }else{
            if(current_tile_size > 1){
                current_tile_size --;
            }
            
        }
        var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
    
    
        for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
            tiles[i].style.width = current_tile_size+"em";
            tiles[i].style.height = current_tile_size+"em";
        }
    });
 </script>
```

This script works but in this case, when the tile size is changed, the parents are affected and their height changes. I want the zoom function to only impact the grid, causing the exceeding portions to be hidden behind the parents as explained before. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please put your code in a [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: what you mean zoom? zoom inside the element or make the element iself bigger ?

Comment: @eladBA I mean make the element bigger

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass transform:scale worked. If you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide overflow in the table if needed and use `transform: scale`.
Because CSS Transform does not affect document flow. The DOM element will occupy it's original position and dimensions within the page flow.

Comment: transform: scale was sufficient